# Stuck on "Using Rails Adapter" when starting script with thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I'm running `bundle exec thin -p 4000 -e sandbox start 2>&1` and I get:

`>> Using rails adapter`

It just hangs there and I don't think that my Rails adapter is running. Does `thin` have a log or something I can see to find out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `foreman` to start things up and running.

Answer (score 0):

look at this site

http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/doc/classes/Thin/Logging.html

it has the info you need to log the adapter

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm new to Rails and inherited this project. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to actually use the logger. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the logger. Any help?